# Is there a way to add text to a function output in html?

Tags: textinput

I am trying to display two randomly generated numbers in a textbox, and I want it to look like this: (x,y). Is there an attribute I can add to my input to make that happen?

```
<input id="result" type="text">

<script>
function diceroll(){
var randnum=Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
document.getElementById("result").value=randnum}
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to roll the dice every time you reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function diceroll() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    let str = '(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
    document.getElementById("result").value = str
}
diceroll();
```

```html
<input id="result" type="text">
```